# NoSuchMethodError with dart.js

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I'm trying to use paper.js with Dart through js.dart.

A lot seems to work, but I also need the method `importSVG` from paper.js. When I try to access it with `js.context.paper.project.importSVG(query("#svg"));` I get `NoSuchMethodError`. It's somehow because the method is injected into project -- see code from paper.js below.

How do I access the `importSVG` method from Dart?

```javascript
/* paper.js */
new function() {
    function importSVG(node, clearDefs) {
            // ...
    }

    Item.inject(/** @lends Item# */{
            /**
             * Converts the passed node node into a Paper.js item and adds it to the
             * children of this item.
             *
             * @param {SVGSVGElement} node the SVG DOM node to convert
             * @return {Item} the converted Paper.js item
             */
            importSVG: function(node) {
                    return this.addChild(importSVG(node, true));
            }
    });

    Project.inject(/** @lends Project# */{
            /**
             * Converts the passed node node into a Paper.js item and adds it to the
             * active layer of this project.
             *
             * @param {SVGSVGElement} node the SVG DOM node to convert
             * @return {Item} the converted Paper.js item
             */
            importSVG: function(node) {
                    this.activate();
                    return importSVG(node, true);
            }
    });
};
```

Comment: Having a quick look at http://paper.js it seems that your call `js.context.paper.project.importSVG(query("#svg"));` is correct. Could you paste the whole error ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "Breaking on exception: NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'importSVG'" thrown from js.dart:1038

Comment: Quite strange. Could you test with the _chrome developer tools_ that you have this method defined in javascript ? In the console enter `paper.project.importSVG`. You should see something like `function (node) { this.activate(); return importSVG(node, true); }`

Comment: Sure, it returns undefined. paper.project returns
_currentStyle: ctor
_index: 0
_scope: ctor
_selectedItemCount: 0
_selectedItems: Object
activeLayer: ctor
layers: Array[1]
  0: ctor
  length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
symbols: Array[0]
__proto__: ctor

Comment: On http://paperjs.org/ I get what I pasted in previous comment. You should have a problem with the javascript code.

Comment: Thanks for your time, you are correct. I was using a CDN: cdnjs.cloudflare which was hosting an older version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Dart call seems correct. The comments on the question tend to show that there's a problem with the javascript import/declaration of `paper.project.importSVG`.